# Eliminar tabla temporal desde laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server, stored-procedure

tengo el siguiente procedimiento en sql server:

```
USE [DWBadamaxRetail]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ConsultaStockSkuCanal]    Script 
Date: 28/01/2019 16:05:27 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      NomAutor
-- Create date: 2019/01/24
-- Description: consulta stock
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConsultaStockSkuCanal] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @fechaini int = 0, 
    @fechafin int = 0 

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT  al.canalventa, id_producto,
        sum(stock) as stock
    into    #tmp_stock_sku
    from    fact.stock_acumulado as st LEFT JOIN dim.almacen as al
        ON  st.id_almacen = al.id_almacen 
    and     st.id_calendario = @fechaini 
    group by al.canalventa, id_producto
    union all
    select  al.canalventa, id_producto,
            sum(stock) as stock
    from    fact.stock_acumulado_diario as st LEFT JOIN dim.almacen as al 
    ON  st.id_almacen = al.id_almacen 
    and     id_calendario = @fechafin
    group by al.canalventa, id_producto 

    select  canalventa, 
            count(distinct p.cod_codigopadre + ' ' + cod_colores) as sku
    from    #tmp_stock_sku tmp
            inner join dim.producto p
            on tmp.id_producto = p.id_producto group by canalventa 
    having sum(stock) > 0 
    order by 1 asc; 

END
```

El cual ejecuto desde mi modelo:

```
   public function stock_sku_canal($fechaini, $fechafin){


    $sql = collect(DB::connection('comments')->select(" EXEC [dbo].[ConsultaStockSkuCanal] @fechaini = $fechaini, @fechafin = $fechafin"))->toArray();

    $names = array_pluck($sql, 'stock','canalventa');

    return $names;

}
```

Como ven, hago uso de una tabla temporal #tmp_stock_sku, mi duda es cómo la borro, la destruyo o la desaparezco al realizar la ejecución desde mi modelo en laravel 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Las tablas temporales son bases de datos de sistemas, dependiendo de tu versión de SQL Server, podrias configurar incluso más de una. Como referencia puedes revisar en la documentación de MSFT [tempdb Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-2017)

Por lo general quedan en la base de datos `tempdb` en el esquema `dbo`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ser así, podrías utilizar la siguiente sintaxis para poder eliminarla

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp_stock_sku') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp_stock_sku
```

En laravel podrias configurar una instrucción que ejecute esa instrucción T-SQL para eliminar la tabla temporal.